# Overload resolution of a qualified name

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-lookup, qualified-name, unqualified-name

Consider this function call:

```
foo::bar();
```

11.3.1.1.1, paragraph 3 [over.call.func] ([N4778](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4778.pdf)) covers this case:

> In unqualified function calls, the name is not qualified by an `->` or `.` operator and has the more general form of a *primary-expression*. **The name is looked up in the context of the function call** following the normal rules for name lookup in function calls...

Here, `foo::bar` is an unqualified name, **in the sense that it's not qualified by `->` or `.`**. So this paragraph applies. Now, the meaning of the phrase "looked up in the context of" is explained in 6.4, paragraph 2 [basic.lookup]:

> A name “looked up in the context of an expression” is looked up **as an unqualified name** in the scope where the expression is found.

However,  `foo::bar` is a qualified name **in the realm of name lookup**. In other words, this combination of paragraphs basically say that, the qualified name `foo::bar` is looked up by the rule of unqualified name lookup. However, I don't think that unqualified name lookup is capable of recursively entering into a narrower scope, i.e., `foo` to `bar`. Is this a defect?

Comment: just curious, why which rules used during lookups would be the matter of any interest? surely there has to be a reason if they included in the document.

Comment: `foo::bar()` can still be in another namespace.

Comment: @Yucel_K This might be a defect in the document, and that's why I'm asking this here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you elaborate more? I'm not sure how your comment is related to my question.

Comment: Not sure by comment is valid though, but `foo::bar` might refer to `N::foo::bar` and not `::foo::bar`. (thanks to `using`, whereas `c.bar()` cannot refer to another `namespace`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, resolving the qualified name `foo::bar` must involve qualified name lookup, not unqualified name lookup. This is true since unqualified name lookup keeps searching **outward** while qualified name lookup does this **inward**. As you can see that this question is tagged under `language-lawyer`, my question was to see if anyone agrees that the standard made a mistake as to mis-tagging this specific case as an example of unqualified name lookup. I think that this is a defect.

Comment: @9room Resolving `foo::bar` implies "resolving `foo`" which involves unqualified name lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think this is a defect. It says

> The name is looked up in the context of the function call **following the normal rules for name lookup in function calls** [...]

As you can see from the part that I highlighted, the standard specifies how the name is supposed to be looked up: By name lookup.

Name lookup involves unqualified, qualified and argument-dependent lookup, so your name is indeed resolved by the qualified name lookup rules.

The "looked up in the context of *expr*" rule doesn't apply here, as it is specified what rule is used. That paragraph only comes into play when it's not. For example, in [[class.qual]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#class.qual-1.3):

> the names in a *template-argument* of a *template-id* are looked up in the context in which the entire *postfix-expression* occurs.

Comment: For future viewers, note that the phrase _looked up in the context of_ in these paragraphs doesn't seem to carry a special meaning with it. IMO, the explicit reference to 6.4 (which I omitted in the above quote) overrides any ambiguity there so that the entire name lookup shall take place, which also includes qualified name lookup.